# SQLAlchemy automap expected tables are missing

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```py
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func
from flask import Flask, jsonify

#################################################
Database Setup
#################################################
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///titanic.sqlite")

# reflect an existing database into a new model
Base = automap_base()
# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

# Save reference to the table
Passenger = Base.classes.passenger
Measurement = Passenger = Base.classes.measurement
```

When I attempt to run this code to set up the database I am getting the following error:

```sh
$ python c:/Users/.../app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 210, in __getattr__
    return self._data[key]
KeyError: 'passenger'
    
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/.../app.py", line 21, in <module>
    Passenger = Base.classes.passenger
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 212, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: passenger
```

I have tried using DB Browser for SQLite to verify that the tables exist and are named correctly, but I am still getting an AttributeError.

Comment: What do you get if you call `print(Base.metadata.tables.keys())` before saving the references to the table?

Comment: I get "dict_keys([])"

Comment: That means that no table has been mapped. Are you sure it’s the correct database in the correct location?